Wrong output from custom big unsigned integer type when checking whether subtraction follow modular arithmetic
Here I am tasked with creating an UnsignedBigInteger class that can handle numbers bigger than a long. Am allowed to use a byte array as the internal representation, uint8_t[].
What I came up with is a UnsignedBigInteger type storing the integer inside an array of uint8_t buckets. I work in 64bit architecture (-m64 flag to the compiler).
I ran into a problem while trying to code an operator- between two of my custom objects. We are dealing with unsigned integers, say a and b: when a < b, a - b should follow the rules of modular arithmetic (refer to this question for further info on modular arithmetic).
Here is my attempt:
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <cassert>

class UnsignedBigInteger {
public:
    constexpr static unsigned long long two_fifty_five{0xffULL}; // 0xff = 0d00000255 = 2^(8) - 1
    constexpr static unsigned long long max_ull{std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max()}; 

    UnsignedBigInteger() = default;
    UnsignedBigInteger(const unsigned long long value) {
        printf("value = %llu\n", value);
        unsigned long long shift{two_fifty_five};
        for (size_t i=0; i!=len; ++i) {
            _value[i] = (value & shift) >> (8 * i);
            printf("_value[%lu] in binary: %llb - shift: %llb\n", i, _value[i], shift);
            shift <<= 8;
        };
        // above is equivalent to:
        // _value[0] = value & 0xff;
        // _value[1] = value & (0xff << 8);
        // _value[2] = value & (0xff << 16); 
        // ... _value[6] = value & (0xff << 56);
    }

    unsigned long long int get() const {
        unsigned long long int result{};
        for (size_t i=0; i!=len; ++i) {
            result += (_value[i] << (8*i));
            printf("get result[%lu] = %llu, or in binary %llb\n", i, result, result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    UnsignedBigInteger operator-(const UnsignedBigInteger& addend) const {

        UnsignedBigInteger result{};
        
        for (size_t i=0; i!=len; ++i) {
            result._value[i] = (_value[i] - addend._value[i]) % two_fifty_five;
            (this->get() < addend.get()) && (result._value[i] == 0) ? 
                (result._value[i] = two_fifty_five) : true;
            printf("subtraction result, buckets: _value[%lu]: %llb\n", i, result._value[i]);
        }

        printf("subtraction result obtained with get(): %llu\n", result.get());

        return result; 
    }

private:
    constexpr static size_t len = 7;
    uint8_t _value[len];
};


int main() {
    // verify you are in 64-bit environment
    constexpr static unsigned long long max_ull{std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max()}; 
    assert(max_ull == 18'446'744'073'709'551'615ULL);  // = 2^64 - 1 = billions of billions
    printf("ULLONG_MAX is set for 64bit arithmetics: %llu - binary: %llb\n\n", max_ull, max_ull);

    printf("Define two UnsignedBigInteger objects: \n");
    UnsignedBigInteger a{13ULL}, b{27ULL};
    
    printf("\nSubtract them:\n");
    UnsignedBigInteger a_minus_b = a - b;
    printf("\nSUBTRACTION RESULT, FROM MAIN() PROGRAM, IS CORRECT:\n");
    printf("a - b = %llu --- in binary %llb\n\n", a_minus_b, a_minus_b);
    
    // should behave like this:
    printf("\nAttempting to reproduce modular arithmetic for unsigned integer subtraction, as below:\n");
    unsigned int five = 5, seven = 7;
    unsigned int aa = five - seven; 
    printf("uint aa = 5 - 7 = %u\n", aa); 
}

Here is the runnable version of MWE above on godbolt link.
It can be seen from the output console that the result of the subtraction is given correctly from the main program (follows modular arithmetic), while the printf from the get() function I set up during debugging seems unable to handle numbers higher than 24-bits (see total break of pattern in chunk of output below, get result[3]).
get result[0] = 242, or in binary 11110010
get result[1] = 65522, or in binary 1111111111110010
get result[2] = 16777202, or in binary 111111111111111111110010
get result[3] = 18446744073709551602, or in binary 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110010
get result[4] = 241, or in binary 11110001
get result[5] = 65521, or in binary 1111111111110001
get result[6] = 16777201, or in binary 111111111111111111110001
subtraction result obtained with get(): 16777201

SUBTRACTION RESULT, FROM MAIN() PROGRAM, IS CORRECT:
a - b = 72057594037927922 

I am puzzled because get() should be the output interface for UnsignedBigInteger. What I print in main is a unsigned long long, which is converted from UnsignedBigInteger implicitly as I did not even set up a type conversion operator.

Since you are using C++, you should use std::cout instead of printf.  One wrong move with the printf format specifier can cause output to display differently (or cause undefined behavior).  The godbolt link shows warnings about this.

@PaulMcKenzie I think most of those warnings regard specifier %b for binary format which has been implemented very recently, so it works by now, but still they left it with warnings popping up. Besides I am not allowed to use the standard library except for <limits> unfortunately

Besides I am not allowed to use the standard library except for  unfortunately -- Unless your teacher, professor, or boss is looking over your shoulder to see what you coded, you could still experiment to see if using std::cout makes a difference or not.

@PaulMcKenzie see if using std::cout makes a difference or not Sounds reasonable, so I gave it a try godbolt no luck however, as std::cout prints the same output for get(), breaking down at 24-bits (result[3]).

That % two_fifty_five in operator- looks wrong. Is it supposed to be & two_fifty_five?

@PeteBecker that % is OK, stands for modulo. According to modular arithmetic, you assign that value when subtraction between two unsigned yields a negative result. It's like as if it's 1AM now, and that means it was 9 PM 4 hours ago: 1 - 4 = 9 (-3 mod 12)

@Giogre — so, you want 255 - 0 to be 0?

@PeteBecker no, but the reverse, 0 - 255 should be =1

Note that clock arithmetic is not like modular arithmetic; clocks count from 1, not 0.

@PeteBecker I'll double check the formula then. It should be that if two unsigned a < b, then a - b = (a - b) % bucket_width (=256 in this 8bit case)

The code you’ve written will give 0 as the result of 255-0. It’s wrong, for the reason I gave you. 8 bit values run from 0 to 255. That % 255 means you’ll only get values from 0 to 254. Try it.

@Giogre — yes, % 256, not % 255. But n % 256 and n & 255 do the same thing when n is unsigned.

@PeteBecker so I did introduce a two_fifty_six godbolt, plugged it in the denominator inside operator- however that did not help. I am available in chat by the way EDIT:updated the godbolt link still no success

You added a constant named two_fifty_six but the operator doesn’t use it. Again: start by getting 255-0 right.

@PeteBecker correct me if I am wrong, but I used the new constant in line 43 of my last godbolt link? I don't think it should appear in line 45 too

Yup, it’s there. I don’t know what that conditional stirs trying to do, so I have no idea what constant it should use. Write an if statement instead. And, again, start by getting 255-0 to work correctly.

@PeteBecker 255 - 0 actually works fine godbolt because it never triggers the ternary conditional operator inside operator- that kicks in in case subtraction is negative

So you’ve made progress, because 255-0 didn’t work correctly before.

@PeteBecker the ternary conditional is actually there to switch empty 00'000'000 buckets into 11'111'111s. Say you have number 27 = 0b00011011, with also 6 buckets of 8-bits each that are all 0s preceding the only populated bucket. If we have 13 -27, all these empty buckets should switch to 1s, hope I clarified this because I see it can be murky

If-statement in place of ternary: godbolt

@Giogre -- The warning at line 76 says: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned long long' but the argument has type 'UnsignedBigInteger' [-Wformat] -- That is very suspicious, as printf has no idea what UnsignedBigInteger is.  Unless there was some type of casting operator defined in UnsignedBigInteger which I am missing, this usage of printf is undefined behavior.

@PaulMcKenzie what's really maddening is that printf statement in line 76 seems to yield a credible result even though I in no way defined the conversion from UnsignedBigInteger to unsigned long long. All the while, the get() member function which should manage the output of UnsignedBigInteger seems unable to handle more than 24 bits for mysterious reasons

You need to either have a casting operator for unsigned long long, or a member function that returns the right type.  As it stands, the code has UB, even though the results seem to be "ok".

@PaulMcKenzie I set up the get() member function for the purpose. Here I use std::cout + get() function in main() godbolt
but get() has some bug that hinders it beyond 24bits (3rd bucket in data array of UnsignedBigInteger)

"What I print in main is a unsigned long long, which is converted from UnsignedBigInteger implicitly" -- No, calling it a conversion is at best misleading. There is no real conversion. You told printf that the parameter is an unsigned long long, so it took the the binary representation of the UnsignedBigInteger and treated it as an unsigned long long. It's closer to a reinterpret_cast than a conversion. Caveat: The preceding is very likely to have happened; officially the behavior is undefined.

@Giogre "but get() has some bug that hinders it beyond 24bits" -- You should fix that bug before worrying about subtraction. You cannot demonstrate that there is a bug in subtraction when that demonstration relies on calling a bugged function (get()).

@JaMiT the get() member function is in lines 29-37 of my last godbolt. It transforms a UnsignedBigInteger into a unsigned long long int by summing the _value buckets stored in the UnsignedBigInteger, opportunely bitwise shifted. Works fine up to 24 bits at the third bucket, then the fourth bucket outputs an unexpectedly big value, and it seems the next remaining buckets after the fourth repeat the storage of the previous ones. Cannot find the bug so I raised this question

@Giogre result += (_value[i] << (8 * i)); -- What if 8 * i exceeds the number of bits represent by a uint8_t?  Shifting a value greater than the number of bits is undefined behavior.

@Giogre If this is the cause of the issue (a uint8_t is not wide enough for the shift to be valid), maybe you should make the proper changes and post this as an answer, since you know what the final results should be?  I don't want to mislead and post answers if the issue hasn't been resolved.

@PaulMcKenzie good call! I have crudely C-cast the uint8_t _value[] buckets as unsigned long long in line 32 godbolt and now results are correctly bitwise shifted as expected them to. Results coincide with those of printf(a_minus_b) in main(), line 77 which we have determined should be undefined behaviour but actually there must be evidently some implicit casting going on

ok.  You can summarize the changes made, what the issue was, etc. into an answer.

@PaulMcKenzie I think i need to rework the logic for when UnsignedBigInteger constructor accepts integers >255

No it actually works good: line 18 _value[i] = (value & shift) >> (8 * i); where result _value[] is uint8_t, while value and shift are both unsigned long long. However they get shifted right and the uint8_t array always captures the 8 bits of interest

@PaulMcKenzie: Given that int must be larger than uint8_t (if uint8_t even exists on the specified platform), operand promotion will apply.  This explains why the problem isn't observed between 8...23 bits, but only when the shift is by 24 bits (now overflows are happening, and int being NOT an unsigned type, overflows aren't safe)  It could happen at only 8 bits of shift, if the code were run on a platform with 15+1 bit int (the minimum allowed), but OP's compiler like most others has a 31+1 bit int.

@BenVoigt Thanks... why would the limit for uint8_t be set to 24bits in my platform? Would think 8bit, as the name of the type uint8_t implies

@Giogre: In _value[i] << (8*i) the left operand is implicitly promoted to int (and the right operand is already size_t)

https://stackoverflow.com/q/46073295/103167 and I'm looking for a C++ question, but the explanation's essentially the same.  Here are the rules that make it apply in C++: https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#2 and https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv#1.5 and https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#1

@BenVoigt I see... so basically in _value[i] << (8*i) the int of 8 * i ends up being the dominant type everything else converts to

@Giogre: The reason the problem starts at 24 bits of shift is that if you have 8 bits of input, the bit number 7, when shifted by 24, ends up in the sign bit.  This is a problem in many versions of C++ but not the latest one...  Shifting by 32 bits (if that's the width of int on your platform) is always a problem.

@Giogre: No... the left-hand side promotes to int.  8 already is an int.  i is a size_t.  (8 * i) is most probably also size_t.  Shift operators don't care about the type of the right-hand side, but they do care about promotion.  "The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.  The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand."  https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#1

@BenVoigt sure the lhs _value[i] is promoted (not converted as I wrote) to int, but that's because of what is found in the rhs, otherwise lhs would have stayed the same type

@Giogre: No.  Promotion is not the same as "find a common type", formally called "the usual arithmetic conversions", and shift operators do not find a common type.  I quoted the relevant rules and also linked to them.

@Giogre "Cannot find the bug [in the get() function] so I raised this question [about subtraction]" -- You don't see the inconsistency here? Keep it simple and ask why get() does not work. Don't needlessly drag subtraction into the picture. Since you know what the difference should be, why not just define UnsignedBigInteger a_minus_b{72057594037927922ULL}; and proceed from there?

@JaMiT Keep it simple and ask why get() does not work. I am not prescient: I certainly did not know where the bug was in advance of asking the question. Were I to know, why write and publish this question in the first place. Without the few commenters here investigating the issue and steering me down the right direction, I probably would never have discovered the bug by myself. I don't have real access to knowledgeable people so the help received here was crucial, I am really grateful to the kindness of Paul McKenzie, Pete Becker and Ben Voigt thank you guys for chiming in

@Giogre " I am not prescient: I certainly did not know where the bug was in advance of asking the question." -- This quote from the original version of your question disputes that: "the printf from the get() function I set up during debugging seems unable to handle numbers higher than 24-bits". You did identify that a bug was in get() prior to asking your question.

@JaMiT Yes that was why I asked the question in the first place, that was what did seem suspicious, among many other aspects. It came out my modular arithmetic logic in the subtraction operator was also slightly faulty. People read that and steered me to the solution. I couldn't have solved this alone. I don't really follow you

As suggested in the comments by @PaulMcKenzie and confirmed by @BenVoigt, the problem laid within UnsignedBigInteger member function get(): components of _values[] - an array of uint8_t which is UnsignedBigInteger data member - are bitwise-shifted leftwards in line
result += (_value[i] << (8*i));

Here, type promotion rules kick in: everything on the right hand side ends up being an int, leading the left hand side to overflow once the bit-shifting reaches the sign bit (24th).
A revised version of the MWE code with godbolt link is below.
All previously appearing compiler warnings were addressed by use of std::cout in place of printf.
Debugging lines were also commented out in order to produce cleaner output.
In addition the get() function is substituted by a conversion operator operator unsigned long long int() sporting a static_cast<unsigned long long> inside, handling the conversion.
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

class UnsignedBigInteger {
public:
    constexpr static unsigned long long two_fifty_five{0xffULL}; // 0xff = 0d00000255 = 2^(8) - 1
    constexpr static unsigned long long max_ull{std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max()}; 
    constexpr static unsigned long long two_fifty_six{0x100ULL}; 

    UnsignedBigInteger() = default;
    UnsignedBigInteger(const unsigned long long value) {
        //printf("value = %llu\n", value);
        unsigned long long shift{two_fifty_five};
        for (size_t i=0; i!=len; ++i) {
            _value[i] = (value & shift) >> (8 * i);
            //printf("_value[%lu] in binary: %hhb - bitmask used here: %llb\n", i, _value[i], shift);
            shift <<= 8;
        };
        // above is equivalent to:
        // _value[0] = value & 0xff;
        // _value[1] = value & (0xff << 8);
        // _value[2] = value & (0xff << 16); 
        // ... _value[6] = value & (0xff << 56);
    }

    operator unsigned long long int() const {
        unsigned long long int result{};
        for (size_t i=0; i!=len; ++i) {
            result += static_cast<unsigned long long>(_value[i]) << (8*i);
            //printf("get result[%lu] = %llu, or in binary %llb\n", i, result, result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    UnsignedBigInteger operator-(const UnsignedBigInteger& addend) const {

        UnsignedBigInteger result{};
        
        for (size_t i=0; i!=len; ++i) {
            result._value[i] = (_value[i] - addend._value[i]) % two_fifty_six;

            // if subtraction in line above yields a negative value, switch empty buckets to 1s:
            if (*this < addend && result._value[i] == 0) 
                result._value[i] = two_fifty_five;

            //printf("subtraction result, buckets: _value[%lu]: %hhb\n", i, result._value[i]);
        }

        return result; 
    }

private:
    constexpr static size_t len = 7;
    uint8_t _value[len];
};


int main() {
    // verify you are in 64-bit environment
    constexpr static unsigned long long max_ull{std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max()}; 
    assert(max_ull == 18'446'744'073'709'551'615ULL);  // = 2^64 - 1 = billions of billions
    printf("ULLONG_MAX is set for 64bit arithmetics: %llu -\nbinary: %llb\n\n", max_ull, max_ull);

    printf("Define two UnsignedBigInteger objects:\n");
    UnsignedBigInteger a{13ULL}, b{27ULL};
    //UnsignedBigInteger a{0ULL}, b{1'000'000ULL};
    std::cout << "a = " << a << "\n" << "b = " << b << std::endl;
    
    printf("\nSubtract them\n(use modular arithmetic if a < b):\n");
    UnsignedBigInteger a_minus_b = a - b;
    std::cout << "a_minus_b = " << a << " - " << b << " = " << a_minus_b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "In binary notation:\n";
    std::cout << "a_minus_b = " << std::format("{:b}", static_cast<unsigned long long>(a)) << " - " << std::format("{:b}", static_cast<unsigned long long>(b)) << " = " << std::format("{:b}", static_cast<unsigned long long>(a_minus_b)) << std::endl;
}

This yields:
ULLONG_MAX is set for 64bit arithmetics: 18446744073709551615 -
binary: 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

Define two UnsignedBigInteger objects:
a = 13
b = 27

Subtract them
(use modular arithmetic if a < b):
a_minus_b = 13 - 27 = 72057594037927922
In binary notation:
a_minus_b = 1101 - 11011 = 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110010

which is as intended.

This is wrong because you ignored "The shift operators << and >> group left-to-right.  The operands shall be prvalues of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed."  https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#1

@BenVoigt wrong because I am referring to narrow casts instead of implicit integral promotions?

Wrong because "overflow for a uint8_t" doesn't matter.  The shift is performed on int and the result is added (shouldn't this be bitwise OR?) into the appropriately-named result variable, which is even wider.  There's nothing being stored to a uint8_t here, so it doesn't matter that it doesn't fit in uint8_t.

@BenVoigt  Regarding the bitshift inside the conversion operator, result is not wider, as both it and static_cast<>(_value[]) are of the type largest unsigned int. Bitwise OR is not needed as I am adding up to result the internal buckets progressively shifted by 8bits at a time, I am not adding two things bitwise

Oh yeah, you are really adding, not reassembling.  So ignore the suggestion of bitwise OR.  unsigned long long int result{}; is quite a bit wider than int.  I'm discussing your description of the original problem (that doesn't have a static_cast), not the "fix".

@BenVoigt edited answer to "Here, type promotion rules kick in: everything on the right hand side ends up being an int, which overflows once the bit-shifting reaches the sign bit (24th)."

Much better, but it's everything on the LEFThand side.

@BenVoigt "everything on the right hand side ends up being an int, leading the left hand side to overflow once ..."

The type of the right-hand side has nothing to do with it.  Built-in shift operators ignore the type of the right operand (as long as it's convertible to some integer).
